# Open a website on client's computer from the server

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my university you can connect to the wireless network but you cannot have internet access unless you log into some site. This site opens up automatically when you connect to the wireless network. If you don't have any browser open, the browser will automatically open on the this site. Even if you close your browser, it will open up again after some time. Can anyone give me an idea on how this is done? I'd like to use it for my school project. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This technique is called `Captive portal`, meaning [following](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal).

> A captive portal is a special web page that is shown before using the
>   Internet normally. The portal is often used to present a login
>   page.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal) This is done by intercepting most packets, regardless of
>   address or port, until the user opens a browser and tries to access
>   the web. At that time the browser is redirected to a web page which
>   may require authentication and/or payment, or simply display an
>   acceptable use policy and require the user to agree. Captive portals
>   are used at many Wi-Fi hotspots, and can be used to control wired
>   access (e.g. apartment houses, hotel rooms, business centers, "open"
>   Ethernet jacks) as well.

But this is not controlled at server side, as internet provider does that and system at starting wifi connect , check of connect using some url , like in mac it is success.html , info here - https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5784008?tstart=0